# Com agrupar uma lista em javascript e calcular os subtotais?

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte lista:

```
nomes = [
  { nome: "flavio", valor: 10 },
  { nome: "flavio", valor: 20 },
  { nome: "fran", valor: 30 },
  { nome: "fran", valor: 40 },
  { nome: "Roberto", valor: 50},
  { nome: "Roberto", valor: 50 }
];
```

Como faço para obter:

```
subtotais = [
  {nome:"flavio", total:30},
  {nome:"fran", total:70},
  {nome:"Roberto", total:10}]
```

Agradeço qualquer ajudar.

Comment: Antes de chegar nesse array, você tem alguma query retorna esses dados?

Comment: O valor do `Roberto` está errado no seu exemplo

Comment: Não estou conseguindo encontrar o V verde para aceitar a resposta.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 4):

Você pode iterar o `array` para obter o resultado esperado:

```js
function somar(antigo) {

  var resultado = [];

  antigo.reduce(function(novo, item) {
    if (!novo[item.nome]) {
      novo[item.nome] = {
        valor: 0,
        nome: item.nome
      };

      resultado.push(novo[item.nome]);
    }

    novo[item.nome].valor += item.valor;

    return novo;
  }, {});
  
  return resultado;
}

console.log(somar([
  { nome: "flavio", valor: 10 },
  { nome: "flavio", valor: 20 },
  { nome: "fran", valor: 30 },
  { nome: "fran", valor: 40 },
  { nome: "Roberto", valor: 50},
  { nome: "Roberto", valor: 50 }
]));
```

Traduzido [desta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29364431/3388148)

**Utilizando `ES6`**:

```js
const somar = (itens) => {
  const total = itens.reduce((acumulador, { nome, valor }) => {
    acumulador[nome] = (acumulador[nome] || 0) + valor;
    return acumulador;
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(total).map((nome) => ({ nome, valor: total[nome] }));
};

// Teste da solução
const nomes = [
  { nome: 'flavio', valor: 10 },
  { nome: 'flavio', valor: 20 },
  { nome: 'fran', valor: 30 },
  { nome: 'fran', valor: 40 },
  { nome: 'Roberto', valor: 50},
  { nome: 'Roberto', valor: 50 }
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(somar(nomes)));
```

Comment: Poxa. Que rápido. Minha primeira vez aqui e fico muito agradecido, Sorack.

Comment: OK. Só pude checar agora. Funcionou perfeitamente. Grato.

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução simples é utilizar um `for` normal para percorrer cada pessoa, e perceber se a pessoa já existe no array agrupado através de [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex). Caso não exista adiciona a nova pessoa, caso contrário soma o valor.

Exemplo:

```js
pessoas = [
  { nome: "flavio", valor: 10 },
  { nome: "flavio", valor: 20 },
  { nome: "fran", valor: 30 },
  { nome: "fran", valor: 40 },
  { nome: "Roberto", valor: 50},
  { nome: "Roberto", valor: 50 }
];

let agrupados = [];
for (let pessoa of pessoas){
  let posicao = agrupados.findIndex(p => p.nome === pessoa.nome);
  if (posicao === -1){ //se não existe
    agrupados.push(pessoa); //adiciona
  }
  else { //se já existe
    agrupados[posicao].valor += pessoa.valor; //soma o valor
  }
}

console.log(agrupados);
```

Comment: Forma antiga mas funciona tb. Grato. Eu iria fazer assim mas queria usar o reduce(). Vou começar a montar minha biblioteca de codigos conseguidos aqui. Valeu mesmo pessoal.